# Problem using join and where sysdate clause at the same time in ORACLE SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, join, where-clause, sysdate

I want to get the game list which is coming for the future, using join and have a filter 'WHERE GAME_DATE > SYSDATE'

```
GAME_DATE,
ARENA,
HOME_TEAM_NAME,
AWAY_TEAM_NAME,
```

GAME table:

```
GAME_DATE DATE
GAME_ID NUMBER
HOME VARCHAR
AWAY VARCHAR
```

TEAM table:

```
TEAM_ID NUMBER
NAME VARCHAR
CITY VARCHAR  <- TO BE "ARENA"
```

This code is working but it is not desired result because home and away attribute are NUMBER, where I want to change these to VARCHAR joined TEAM table:

```
select game_date, home, away 
from game 
where game_date > sysdate;
```

but this code which uses join and sysdate at the same time is NOT working:

```
SELECT g.game_date, t1.city "ARENA",  t1.name "HOME", t2.name "AWAY"
from game g
join team t1 on g.home = t1.team_id 
join team t2 on g.away = t2.team_id;
where g.game_date > sysdate;
```

It returns " SQL command not properly ended". Which line is wrong?

Comment: Maybe drop the semicolon at the end of this line in your query: `join team t2 on g.away = t2.team_id;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove semicolon from 4th line:

```
SELECT g.game_date, t1.city "ARENA",  t1.name "HOME", t2.name "AWAY"
from game g
join team t1 on g.home = t1.team_id 
join team t2 on g.away = t2.team_id
where g.game_date > sysdate;
```

Comment: Thanks. Really easy mistake.